# Tabular Model Not Caching Results

Tags: caching, ssas, mdx, ssas-tabular

Can anyone, someone point me in the direction of how to troubleshoot why a Tabular model that I have built does not seem to want to cache query results?

It is my understanding that MDX queries to Tabular model will be cached, however with our model they never seem to be! And I can't figure out why..

My best guess is that it's memory pressure, and the system is clearing down the RAM, but even that is a guess..

Are there any counters, DMVs, or other perfmon stats etc that i can use to actually see what is going on and check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of places to look, but I'd recommend starting with a Profiler/xEvent trace. Below is an example of 2 runs of the same MDX query.

---

The first run is on a cold-cache...
[image]

The second run is on a warm-cache and you can see that it is resolving the query from cache...
[image]

---

This is much easier to see if you can isolate the query on non-production server (e.g. test/dev environment). There are quite a few reasons why a particular query may not be taking advantage of the cache...but you need to first confirm that it is not using the cache.

Comment: I've only gotten around to checking into this today a bit more, and it turns out the main culprit that i have is that a report has a ton of WITH MEMBER commands before the MDX which is preventing it from caching... apparently..

guess i'll have to push these down into the model, which is good enough for me..

ty.